# Twitter button and Google Page Speed

Tags: javascript, twitter, pagespeed

On a page that has Twitter's Tweet buttons, I get warnings from [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights):

> The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 3 request(s) and 52.0KiB.
>   http://platform0.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html
>   http://platform1.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html
>   http://platform2.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html
>
> The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 4.6KiB.
>   http://platform0.twitter.com/widgets/images/tweet.png
>   http://platform1.twitter.com/widgets/images/tweet.png
>   http://platform2.twitter.com/widgets/images/tweet.png

Why does Twitter's widgets.js serve up different URLs for each of these and is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

It probably serves them from different URLs to load-balance the requests; however, as page speed correctly points out, this is actually a bad idea to do within the context of a single request (though it makes sense to rotate the domains for distinct requests), since it results in a cache miss of the resource.

Comment: So basically, not much that can be done about it unless Twitter change the way they implement it?

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same thing. Only thing you can do is to make sure these buttons don't slow down your website, but only themselves. Open up Webkit Inspector and see how resources are downloaded. Also do that in Firebug/IE to see if they behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer on the twitter for websites forum, by a Twitter engineer: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8671